# Blank Checkout after adding items to basket

Tags: magento2

i get this bug of adding items to basket and have blank checkout when i proceed and only see the summary instead of the delivery details etc.

magento 2.1.0
usually comes when i make second order with customer
guest accounts are fine

code of javascript in console browser

```
TypeError: value is undefined[Learn More]  rules.min.js:6:212
.max_text_length< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules.min.js:6:212
validate http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator.min.js:2:47
validator/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator.min.js:4:196
_.all http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/underscore.min.js:14:571
validator http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator.min.js:4:110
.validate http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract.min.js:7:678
.onUpdate http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract.min.js:8:97
bound  self-hosted
ko_subscribable_fn.notifySubscribers http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.min.js:122:1
ko.observable/observable.valueHasMutated http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.min.js:134:230
observable http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.min.js:131:696
setNested http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/mage/utils/objects.min.js:3:38
.nested http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/mage/utils/objects.min.js:9:127
Element<.set http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element.min.js:10:312
updateValue http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/links.min.js:9:1
bind_applyFunctionN self-hosted
bind_invokeFunctionN self-hosted
bound updateValue self-hosted
trigger/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/events.min.js:6:122
forEach self-hosted
trigger http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/events.min.js:6:58
.trigger http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/events.min.js:10:8
Element<._notifyChanges/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element.min.js:15:226
forEach self-hosted
Element<._notifyChanges http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element.min.js:15:187
Element<.set http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element.min.js:10:352
.initialize/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping.min.js:2:510
Registry.prototype._resolveRequest http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry.min.js:16:422
Registry.prototype._addRequest http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry.min.js:16:84
Registry.prototype.get http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry.min.js:15:1
async http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry.min.js:3:212
bound async self-hosted
.initialize http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping.min.js:2:358
.wrapSuper/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/mage/utils/wrapper.min.js:3:178
createConstructor/UiClass http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/class.min.js:3:1
initComponent http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/core/renderer/layout.min.js:7:51
jQuery.Callbacks/fire http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/jquery.min.js:212:281
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/jquery.min.js:217:198
.Deferred/</deferred[tuple[0]] http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/jquery.min.js:219:31
jQuery.Callbacks/fire http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/jquery.min.js:212:281
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/jquery.min.js:217:198
.Deferred/</deferred[tuple[0]] http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/jquery.min.js:219:31
loadSource/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/core/renderer/layout.min.js:6:107
newContext/context.execCb http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:112:123
context.execCb http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/milano/en_GB/mage/requirejs/resolver.min.js:9:140
newContext/Module.prototype.check http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:56:449
newContext/Module.prototype.enable/</< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:72:98
bind/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:11:48
newContext/Module.prototype.emit/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:74:76
each http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:3:77
newContext/Module.prototype.emit http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:74:40
newContext/Module.prototype.check http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:61:83
newContext/Module.prototype.enable/</< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:72:98
bind/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:11:48
newContext/Module.prototype.emit/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:74:76
each http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:3:77
newContext/Module.prototype.emit http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:74:40
newContext/Module.prototype.check http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:61:83
newContext/Module.prototype.enable/</< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:72:98
bind/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:11:48
newContext/Module.prototype.emit/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:74:76
each http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:3:77
newContext/Module.prototype.emit http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:74:40
newContext/Module.prototype.check http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:61:83
newContext/Module.prototype.enable/</< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:72:98
bind/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:11:48
newContext/Module.prototype.emit/< http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:74:76
each http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:3:77
newContext/Module.prototype.emit http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:74:40
newContext/Module.prototype.check http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:61:83
newContext/Module.prototype.enable http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:73:280
newContext/Module.prototype.init http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:54:139
callGetModule http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:74:194
newContext/context.completeLoad http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:103:1
newContext/context.onScriptLoad http://www.xojewels.co.uk/pub/static/_cache/merged/0f135e57cc73bc6a40c10d82af579ad4.min.js:112:322
```

Comment: xojewels.co.uk is the site